# knockout sort sometimes skips a record

Tags: jquery, sorting, knockout.js

I have a generic function to handle sorting. when sorting dates knockout .sort appears to be skipping a record on occasion.  below is a snippet of the code.  when the field is dates it'll skip a record and sort the rest.  descending sort works fine.

```
      self.OneTrueSortLocal = function (a, e) {

            var us = this;
            c = $(e.currentTarget),
            sortby = c.data('sortby').split('.')[1],
            dataSet = c.data('sortby').split('.')[0];

            if (c.is('.sorted_DSC')) {
                sortASC(); }
            function sortASC() {
                us[dataSet].sort(function (a, b) {
                    return a[sortby] == b[sortby]  ? 0 : a[sortby] < b[sortby] ? -1 : 1;
                });
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

not 100% sure why, but adding a check for nulls solved this.

```
 var aVal = a || '';
    var bVal = b || '';
    return aVal < bVal ? -1 : 1;
```